# list is not showing in android

Tags: android, list, listview

I am populating a list by the following code .

```
public void refreshSmsInbox() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(
                Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
        int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
        int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
        if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst())
            return;
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        List<String> smsBody = new ArrayList<String>();
        String fromNumber = "";
        do {
            if (pre_address.equals(smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress))) {
                String str = "SMS From: "
                        + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress) + "\n"
                        + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) + "\n";
                fromNumber = smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress);
                smsBody.add(smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody));
            //  arrayAdapter.add(str);
            }
        } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
          arrayAdapter = new SmsArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.row_item,smsBody,fromNumber);
          smsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
```

The code of SmsArrayAdapter is as follows :

```
public class SmsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    List<String> smsBody;
    List<Boolean> Status;
    Context context;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    String fromNumber ; 

    public SmsArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> smsBody,
             String fromNumber) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.smsBody = smsBody;
    //  this.Status = Status;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.fromNumber = fromNumber;
    }

     public static class ViewHolder{

         public TextView textfrom;
         public TextView text_sms; 

     }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textfrom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_from);
            holder.textfrom.setText(" SMS FROM "+fromNumber);
            holder.text_sms = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_sms);
            holder.text_sms.setText(smsBody.get(position));


            /************ Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        return view;
    }

}
```

But the list is not showing . Why ? Where is the error ? How can I solve this ?

Comment: Nothing is in logcat .

Comment: Check by adding Log print the list size and check whether list is empty or not. Try to debug it

Comment: print size of `smsBody` inside adapter

Comment: The list size is 26 .

Comment: Change the "if (convertView == null)" to if (view== null)  and check it.

Comment: `//  arrayAdapter.add(str);` is commented! so nothing goes into you array that holds the strings...

Comment: for FSM sake! why, oh why you do not use CursorAdapter ... such adapter  would be automagically reload on new SMS ... also it takes less memory as you do not store all sms in ArrayList but using cursor directly ...

Comment: [thats it](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/c6182418fd1c387bf5b6) ... of course you can use ViewBinder to build better item row but still using CursorAdapter is easier ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your SmsArrayAdapter constructor remove this

```
 super(context, resource);
```

Add this

```
 super(context, resource,smsBody);
```

This is used by ArrayAdapter super class. otherwise the list is always null. It will not call your getView until you use this.

```
public class SmsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


    List<String> smsBody;
    List<Boolean> Status;
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    String fromNumber ; 

    public SmsArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> smsBody,
             String fromNumber) {
        super(context, resource,smsBody);
        this.smsBody = smsBody;
    //  this.Status = Status;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.fromNumber = fromNumber;               
    }  

     public class ViewHolder{

         public TextView textfrom;
         public TextView text_sms; 

     }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textfrom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_from);

            holder.text_sms = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_sms);              


            /************ Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.textfrom.setText(" SMS FROM "+fromNumber);
        holder.text_sms.setText(smsBody.get(position));
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: you don't use my entire code. just replace the constructor of your smsArrayAdapter

Comment: Thanks . This is a nice answer .

Answer (score 0):

I implemented your code after some modifications and the list is showing now, below is the code

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);

        /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textfrom = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.textView_from);
        holder.textfrom.setText(" SMS FROM "+fromNumber);
        holder.text_sms = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.textView_sms);
        holder.text_sms.setText(smsBody.get(position));


        /************ Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
        convertView .setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView .getTag();

    return convertView ;
}
```

Comment: Sorry , Using your code , thew list is not showing .

Comment: Then, check your getCount method in adapter; may be some problem out there

Comment: I have not implemented getCount method